# Django forms error 'got multiple values for keyword argument 'choices''

Tags: python, django, forms

Getting a strange error when defining my django forms. I get the error:

```
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'choices'
```

This happens with both TestForm and SpeciesForm (quoted below); basically both forms with the 'choices' keyword argument. **init**() is never explicitly called, and the forms aren't even instantiated in the view yet. There's one ModelForm and one plain Form.

```
from django import forms as f
from orders.models import *

class TestForm(f.Form):
    species = f.ChoiceField('Species', choices=Specimen.SPECIES)
    tests = f.MultipleChoiceField('Test', choices=Test.TESTS, widget=f.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    dna_extraction = f.CharField('DNA extraction', help_text='If sending pre-extracted DNA, we require at least 900 ng')

class SpeciesForm(f.ModelForm):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('blood', 'Blood'),
        ('dna', 'Extracted DNA'),
    )
    dam_provided = f.BooleanField('DAM', help_text='Is dam for this specimen included in sample shipment?')
    sample_type = f.ChoiceField('Type of sample', choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    dna_concentration = f.CharField('DNA concentration', help_text='If sending extracted DNA, approximate concentration')

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['order']
        model = Specimen
```

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure why this is happening as the forms are pretty bare-bones.

Comment: The traceback isn't just random noise, you know: it contains useful debugging information. Please post it.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: +1. Your comment cracked me up.

Comment: This is a strange one. I can reproduce it consistently and can't seem to find a way around it. Strange indeed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py#L647

```
647     def __init__(self, choices=(), required=True, widget=None, label=None,
648                  initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):
649         super(ChoiceField, self).__init__(required=required, widget=widget, label=label,
650                                         initial=initial, help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs)
```

use:

```
species = f.ChoiceField(label='Species', choices=Specimen.SPECIES)
tests = f.MultipleChoiceField(label='Test', choices=Test.TESTS, widget=f.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

and:

```
sample_type = f.ChoiceField(label='Type of sample', choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

---

This is assuming that your choices are valid. Not sure what Specimen.SPECIES and Test.TESTS are. Those should be iterable of two-tuples according to:

> ChoiceField.choices
>
> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of
>   2-tuples to use as choices for this
>   field. This argument accepts the same
>   formats as the choices argument to a
>   model field. See the model field
>   reference documentation on choices for
>   more details.

Comment: Thanks for that! I think this question highlights some usability issues with form fields (and models vs forms to an extent). Intuitively I assume I can give a label to these like I would any other form field.